# Проблемы с react native в реальном времени на androide

Tags: laravel, react-native

Разрабатываю приложения на react native, делаю что бы приложения работало в реальном времени, сделал такую связку expo - 49, Laravel, pusher - server.

```
const connectToWebSocket = async () => {
try {
  const ws = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    Pusher,
    key: appConfig.apiKay,
    wsHost: appConfig.backendUrl,
    wssHost: appConfig.backendUrl,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: true,
    encrypted: true,
    cluster: 'eu',
    auth: {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${props.authToken}`,
      },
    },
  });
  const channel = ws.channel('user-online-chat-channel');   
  channel
    .subscribed(() => {})
    .listen('UserOnlineChatEvent', (e) => {
      set_user_online();
    });

  let typingTimer;  
  const channel_typing = ws.channel('typing-message-chat-channel');
  channel_typing
    .subscribed(() => {})
    .listen('TypingMessageEvent', (e) => {
      if (e.typingMessageData.companionId === props.userId) {
        setTyping(true);
        clearTimeout(typingTimer); 
        typingTimer = setTimeout(() => {
          setTyping(false);
        }, 500); 
      }
    });  
} catch (error) {
  console.log('error', error);
}
```

};

когда запускаю приложения все работает нормально, но когда перехожу в режим сна, потом выхожу с него то adroid перестает слушать канал. Может кто то сталкивался с таким ? Может нужно использовать свой сервер вместо pusher ? Спасибо.